# Mac Mini Display Size

Tags: macos

I have a new Mac Mini connected to my HDTV with an HDMI cable and the desktop is larger than my screen so I can't see the menu bar at the top.  How do I adjust this?

Answer (score 1):

Go into System Preferences - Display - adjust the Underscan scale.

Answer (score 0):

- System Preferences
- Display
- Adjust the resolution

Adjusting the resolution can be somewhat of a personal preference depending on how you want it to be sized. After you've done that, it should always look that way when you have it connected to that particular HDTV.

Answer (score 0):

Also many HDTVs have a way to zoom in and out for when the signal doesn't fill the screen. Look for a zoom button (or some such...) on its remote control